# How do I make a Microsoft Word application appear on top of the Microsoft Access for which instantiated it?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a Microsoft Access form which will display a Microsoft Word app with a blank document when a particular button is clicked using the following code :

```
Set wrdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
wrdApp.Visible = True
Set wrdDoc = wrdApp.Documents.Add ' create a new document
```

All is fine except I can never get the Word window to appear on top of the Access window. It just appears in the task bar.

Basically, I want to use Microsoft Word as a pop-up rich text editor.

How can I position the newly opened Microsoft Word app on top of the Microsoft Access form which instantiated it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After much trail and error, I've found the solution:

```
If Tasks.Exists("Microsoft Word") Then
   AppActivate "Microsoft Word"
End If
```

Comment: You should accept this as the answer, even if you answered it yourself :-)

Comment: Worked for me but I have to add the document name. Something like "MyDocName.docx - Microsoft Word"

Answer (score 2):

GeneQ's own answer didn't work for me. What did work was

```
Set w = New Word.Application
w.Visible = True
w.Activate
w.WindowState = wdWindowStateMaximize
```

Comment: Good answer. I tried the above logic on something I am working on and i had tried GeneQ with not much success. I understand what the code is doing. Its say make it visible, activate it and set the window state.